# Terminal sudo commands not showing output

Tags: lxterminal

I'm trying to run the following commands from terminal on my Pi. The tutorials I'm following show these should output something to terminal. I cannot get anything to return. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

`sudo service sabnzbdplus start` and `sudo ddclient -debug -verbose -noquiet`

Edit/ To include screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Posting a screenshot would be helpful in this situation.

Comment: @jeffresc, sorry I've edited. the screenshot doesn't provide much help lol

Comment: The sabnzbdplus tutorial is long, this link is for the ddclient command: https://samhobbs.co.uk/2015/01/dynamic-dns-ddclient-raspberry-pi-and-ubuntu

Comment: FYI - the commands seem to work, as the ddclient and sabnzbdplus are running, they just don't seem to output as they should.

Comment: How can you tell `ddclient` is running if it does not produce an output?

Comment: Because it updated my domain name servers and when I run `top` I can see the daemon running. It's not every command that has this issue. Something simple like `uptime` works fine. And installing packages. I just noticed these had no output.

Comment: But in the question you said you were executing `sudo ddclient -debug -verbose -noquiet` and it did not produce an output, right? This has nothing to do with the daemon.

Comment: *"The tutorials I'm following.."* You should include a link to those because they are often outdated, mistaken, or both.  The duplicate question answers your first question about `service`.  You should ask another one to focus on your problems with `ddclient` since saying (in essense) "somethings produce output and some other things don't" is not a useful approach to solving a problem.  You need to deal with one issue at a time.

Comment: The "unix way" is to see nothing as a sign that it simply worked.  A lot of commands have a -v option so you can see verbose output.